# How can I access the images folder from code behind

Tags: image, sharepoint, directory, code-behind

I have an image on the images folder of a SharePoint 2013 site. I want to access this folder (and this image) to load it on a carousel, but I don't know where is it and how I can access to it.

Can anyone helps me? Thanks!

I upload an screenshot, hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the image URL like below:

[image]

Then use the URL in  to show the image.

```
<img src="/sites/team/PublishingImages/Capture32.PNG"/>
```

If you want to get image using C# in Server, we can get images library and get all list items.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sp2013/sites/team"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists["Images"];
        foreach (SPListItem item in list.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.File.ServerRelativeUrl);
        }
    }
}
```